# Regular expressions in Python. Can anybody help a newbie?

Tags: python, regex

This simple problem is kiling me. I posted something earlier about trying to clean up a database of addresses and somebody suggested GeoPy to check the validity of the addresses. Great tool which I did not know, but before doing that, I need to clean up the database a little bit, since geopy will not deal with messy formatting.
The solution is to use regular expressions, which I think I have sort of fixed for most of the types of addresses I seen in the database. 
Nevertheless, I am having problems with the last RegExp I defined (called r4 in the code), because it is retuning part of the first parenthesis which I don't need, and I don't know why I have a extra white spaces when it returns the last group (City: London, Country: England). 
Can anybody help?

```
import re

r1 = '\s*ForeignZip.*--\s*([\d\.]+)'
r2 = '(\w+)\W*,\W*(\w*)'
r3 = '(?<=\().*?(?=\))'
r4 = '(\w+\W\()'

Location = ['   ForeignZip (xxx) -- 734.450','Washington, DC.','London (England)']

for item in Location:
    print item
    match1 = re.search(r1,item)
    match2 = re.search(r2,item)
    match3 = re.search(r3,item)
    match4 = re.search(r4,item)

    if match1:
        print 'pattern 1 found:', match1.group(1)

    elif match2:
        print 'pattern 2 found: City :' + match2.group(1) + ", State :" + match2.group(2)

    elif match3:
        print 'pattern 3 found: City: ', match4.group() + ", Country :" + match3.group(0)

    else:
        print 'no match'
```

This returns

```
   ForeignZip (xxx) -- 734.450
pattern 1 found: 734.50
Washington, DC.
pattern 2 found: City :Washington, State :DC
London (England)
pattern 3 found: City:    London (, Country :England
```

Comment: Your main problem is that `\(` is *inside* your capture group. If you don't want to include it in the capture group, but still want to use it to match, place it outside of the parentheses in your regex. Also, It's inefficient to evaluate all 4 patterns. Why don't you check to see if a match is found after each regex is run, that way, if you find a match with the first pattern, you can avoid evaluating all the rest of the patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little changing of your later regexes is necessary ... There are probably a million ways to do this, but here is one.:

```
r3 = r'(\w+)\s+\((\w+)\)'   #Match a word (group1), whitespace followed by a '(' then another word (group2) and finally a closing ')'
```

Or to make whitespace completely insignificant:

```
r3 = r'(\s*(?:\w+\s*)*)\s*\(\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\)'
```

which basically is the previous regex except it replaces `\w+` with `(?:\w+\s*)*` which allows multiple words to be matched, but doesn't capture them -- it leaves the "groups" the same since `(?:...)` never saves the string it matched anywhere.

and now change the third test to:

```
elif match3:
    print 'pattern 3 found: City : '+ match3.group(1) + ", Country :" + match3.group(2)
```

I also removed r4 since it isn't necessary anymore... (Also changed the ',' to a '+' for consistency and added a space in 'City:')

Also note that when dealing with regex, it is often nice to use "raw" strings (this prevents python from mangling tokens in your string.  To test the difference, try:

```
print ("\n")  #prints newline
print (r"\n") #prints "\n"
```

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Be sure to see the other answer too ... They explain the behavior you were getting very well (specifically why you had a trailing parenthesis).  I just wrote my answer the way I did because it seems like a waste to use 2 re's (with lookahead and lookbehind -- yuck) is overly complicated when only one re will do the trick (without the lookahead/behind).

Answer (score 2):

Change r4 to the following

```
r4 = '\w+\W'
```

Also in,

```
elif match3:
        print 'pattern 3 found: City: ', match4.group() + ", Country :" + match3.group(0)
```

you have put a "," after City instead of a "+" which is putting the whitespace. Change it to the following.

```
elif match3:
        print 'pattern 3 found: City: ' + match4.group() + ", Country :" + match3.group(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had not noticed the ",". Great feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this:

```
(\w+\W\()
```

First, you are saving a reference with the outer-most parens to anything that's match inside them, so:

```
\w+\W\(
```

...note the `\(` - which matches a literal open paren

Also, I'm not a Python guy, but is the comma here supposed to be a plus sign by chance?

```
City: ', match4.group() + ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns the parenthesis because it's part of the pattern:  `\(`

You could do this:

```
r4 = '(\w+\W)\('
[...]
print 'pattern 3 found: City: ', match4.group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. re.compile speeds up things if you are in a loop
2. big regexes are incredibly efficient
3. a group dict can tell you where you found something

#

```
finder = re.compile('\s*ForeignZip.*--\s*(?P<fzip>[\d\.]+)|(?P<uscity>\w+)\W*,\W*(?P<state>\w*)|(?P<fcity>\w+)\W*\((?P<country>\w*)\)')
[finder.match(l).groupdict() for l in ll]
```

returns:

```
[{'country': None,
  'fcity': None,
  'fzip': '734.450',
  'state': None,
  'uscity': None},
 {'country': None,
  'fcity': None,
  'fzip': None,
  'state': 'DC',
  'uscity': 'Washington'},
 {'country': 'England',
  'fcity': 'London',
  'fzip': None,
  'state': None,
  'uscity': None}]
```

Comment: Excellent solution. This template will help me a great deal in other parts of my project. Thanks. Cheers!